# Which to use in oder to get current time in javascript, Date() or new Date()?

Tags: javascript

If I am passing current time as an argument to function, which way is correct, `Date()` or `new Date()`? Take the following code for example, which one is better?

```js
function logTime(time) {
    console.log(time);
}

//One
var now = new Date();
logTime(now);

//Two
logTime(new Date());

//Three
logTime(Date());
```

Comment: What results did you get, and how did you feel about them? You can test this stuff, you know. :)

Comment: Well, in fiddle, all three work.. I'm kinda confused now, having expected the third to fail.

Comment: Well, Samer has your answer. But here's a good trick. Try `typeof Date()` and `typeof new Date()`. You'll see which is more useful.

Comment: @MightyPork: `new Date()` creates a `Date` object, but when you use it in `alert()` it will automatically convert it to a string.  The third just returns the string.  So if all you do with the `new Date()` is give it to `alert()`, there won't be any difference.  The difference is when you assign some other variable to `new Date()`, now you can use that object to access other date functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably better to use `new Date`, because you then get a real Date object.

```
> var d = Date();
undefined
> d
'Thu Aug 01 2013 02:22:19 GMT+0200 (CEST)'
> typeof d
'string'
```

Date, when used as a normal function, returns a String. When used as a constructor, it returns an object having the Date prototype, thus you can use the methods `getTime`, `getSeconds` etc.

```
> d = new Date();
Thu, 01 Aug 2013 00:24:41 GMT
> typeof d
'object'
> d.getTime();
1375316681520
> d.getSeconds();
41
```

Answer (score 2):

`Date()` will only output the timestamp

`new Date()` will return an instance of `Date` which you can use to call it's functions. It's more useful with the `new` when you are passing arguments to set a date manually.

Comment: Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/GuHGC/ It looks like all three return the same stuff.

Comment: @Samer `Date()` doesn't actually return the timestamp. It [imitates `new Date().toString()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.2). @MightyPork `alert(new Date())` will call `toString()` as well, amounting to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, the `new` operator is essential if you need something from its properties. Read the *note*-block here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

... to the *caching*-thing: it makes no sense to store it in a variable, since you just need the timestamp.

Comment: imprescindible (es) = essential (en)